# install VMware Tools on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, vmware-player

I'm new in Linux OS's, and I'm trying to install VMware Tools on Ubuntu 9.10, but I don't know how. I just installed alien, but no luck with the tools :(

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific? What exactly did you try to do? And how did that fail?

Comment: I copyed VMware*.rpm to Downloads and after run in terminal
alien -i VMware*.rpm

Comment: i have never worked under Linux, this is my first time, just installed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First Install VMWare server ---->[HOWTO Install VMWare Server](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-vmware-server-in-ubuntu-710-gutsy-gibbon.html)
- Then Install VMWare Tools -----> [HOWTO Install VMWare Tools](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-vmware-tools-in-ubuntu.html)

(Links are from ubuntugeek.com)

Comment: It appears the links you referenced no longer work (or at least they didn't for me.  Which is part of the reason link-only answers are frowned upon.